# How do I argue that the Walrasian equilibrium is unique?

Tags: walrasian

Consider an economy with 1 consumer and 1 firm. There are only 2 goods, leisure $l$ and corn $c$ and the consumer is endowed with 24 hours of leisure. The consumer's utility function is $u(c,l)=cl$. The production set of the firm is $Y=\{(-l,y):y\leq \sqrt{l}\}$. Let $w$ and $p$ be the price of leisure and corn respectively.

The question asks us to find a Walrasian equilibrium, then argue that it is unique.

First I tried to find the WE. The firm maximizes profits by
\begin{align}
\max py-wl\\
s.t.\;c=\sqrt{l}
\end{align}
We can find the labor demand is $l_d^*=\left(\frac{p}{2w}\right)^2$ and $y^*=\frac{p}{2w}$. The profits earned by firm is $\frac{p^2}{4w}$.

The consumer maximizes utility by
\begin{align}
\max &\;cl\\
s.t. \;&pc+wl=24w+\frac{p^2}{4w}
\end{align}
By Lagrangian and FOC, I got $c^*=\frac{12w}{p}+\frac{p}{8w}$ and $l^*=12+\frac{p^2}{8w^2}$. Since labor market clears: $\left(\frac{p}{2w}\right)^2+12+\frac{p^2}{8w^2}=24$, I got $\frac{p^2}{w^2}=32$. Normalize $w^*=1$, I got $p^*=4\sqrt{2}$. So $c^*=2\sqrt{2},l_d^*=8,l^*=16$.

Assuming that the WE I found is correct. How do I show that the WE is unique?

Comment: Every Walrasian equilibrium must be Pareto optimal by the first welfare theorem and every Pareto efficient allocation is a Walrasian equilibrium after transfers by the second welfare theorem. With a single agent, Pareto efficiency is utility maximization under technology constraints and there are no notrivial transfers from an agent to themself. So you can show that maximizing utility under technological constraints gives a unique solution.